# Visual Studio: How to run a bunch of web performance .webtest files and get a result report?

Tags: visual-studio, performance-testing

I remember running a set of test cases and generating a report (.html) using Selenium and also TestNG. I would like to know how to do this for a set of .webtest files that I recorded using Visual Studio 2013. I can run them individually but how about one by one automatically and getting a final result that says which tests failed.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a load test in Visual studio, add all the wanted tests, set a constant user load of 1. Then all the tests will run one after another. The load tests results will include the pass/fail counts. Setting a higher use load may be useful, depending on your application, and the whole test will run faster.

The "Details" page will show all the executed tests on a time-graph, a tick box allows the failed tests to be shown in red.

If you set each web test to stop on the first error then the error page in the results should name precisely the tests that failed, and the reason.

The "Summary" page will give a summary of the results, it may be copied (use right-click context menu)  into Word document and then edited as needed.

Which test is executed and when is chosen according to the "Test mix model" by Visual Studio, some of these models are based on random numbers. With a user load of one it may be best to select the "Test mix based on sequential test order". The "Test mix percentage based on the number of tests started" should also work but I can imagine occasionally getting a test run where one test is executed twice and another not executed. If more than one virtual user is used then the "Test mix based on sequential test order" is probably the wrong choice. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514186.aspx) for more on test mix models.

Comment: Can you help me please? I've created a load test containing some webtests, set it to be ran by one user based on sequential test order in one iteration. And now only one of that webtests runs during running of this load test. I've tried to change all settings but it didn't help.

Comment: @donRumatta "Iteration" means one execution of one webtest. With (say) five webtests, set the number of iterations to five.